# Numerically integrate with non-linear steps?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Suppose I want to numerically solve an ODE, but I know a little about its behavior locally.  Is there any way to use that information as part of an integrator?

For instance, suppose I have:

$$ax'' + bx' + cx + f(x, x', t) = 0$$

This equation almost looks like a damped spring, which has a closed form solution $\large{Ce^{\gamma t}}$, for complex coefficients $C$ and $\gamma$.  But that extra $f(x, x', t)$ term needs to be accounted for.  For something like Runge-Kutta we take steps by linearizing the equation, but then in a case like this that would mean we have to take on the work of solving the damped spring equation in addition to the $f(x, x', t)$ term.

Instead of taking linear steps to each new time step, could we take steps from $t_0$ to $t_0 + h$ by solving: $d = f(x(t_0), x'(t_0), t_0), \ ax'' + bx' + cx + d = 0$ for a closed form?  The idea being that it would let us take a larger step $h$.